# Returning the latest version of a document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am in need of some help with returning only the latest version of the documents that I have indexed in elasticsearch.

My documents have a field called `version`(for internal system versioning) and I index a new document every time there is an update made and increment the version field for the new document

How would I query the index so that it only returns the the latest version out of n amount, where `"id": n"`

**EDIT**

The documents that are being versioned have an id with `.n` version number appended at the end and I want to return the latest version of each of these within an index using the `version` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around. I had to add a `bool isLatestVersion` Property onto my object and I do a query that filters on that.

Answer (score 1):

So each time a new document is added the version field increments by 1 right.

Then version with maximum value would be the latest version. You can use max aggregation to get that.

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "latest" : { "max" : { "field" : "version" } }
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need to specify anything in the mapping for the `id` field?

Comment: Then no special mapping required. curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search" -d'
{
   "aggs": {
      "latest": {
         "max": {
            "field": "version"
         }
      }
   }
}'

Comment: ok, tried it. There is one slight problem in that there will be multiple documents with different Id's and I want to return the latest version of each of there within an index